# Interacting with Bokeh Server in JupyterHub

Tags: python, bokeh, jupyterhub

I've got a [simple bokeh interaction notebook](https://gist.github.com/rsignell-usgs/dc4de1264b85ca762571e976f70b74e5) that captures the coordinates  the user draws, and it works in Jupyter just fine:

[image: 2018-07-03_6-52-18]

```
import numpy as np

N = 500
x = np.linspace(0, 3, N)
y = np.linspace(0, 3, N)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = np.sin(xx) * np.cos(yy)

from bokeh import events
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_notebook()

geom = {}
global geom

def print_event(attributes=[]):
    def python_callback(event):
        geom.update(event.__dict__['geometry'])
    return python_callback

def modify_doc(doc):
    p = figure(x_range=(0, 3), y_range=(0, 3), 
      tools='reset,box_select,lasso_select,poly_select', plot_height=300)
    p.image(image=[z], x=0, y=0, dw=3, dh=3, palette='Spectral11')
    p.on_event(events.SelectionGeometry, print_event(attributes=['geometry']))
    doc.add_root(p)

show(modify_doc)

print(geom)
```

but in JupyterHub the `show(modify_doc)` doesn't produce a plot, and the developer console shows that JS failed to load response data from this request:

```
http://localhost:43474/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=111c97fa-dbc8-437c-9770-471dc23fb13f&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:43474&resources=none
```

Since I access the Dask Dashboard on my jupyterhub at

http://pangeo.esipfed.org/user/rsignell-usgs/proxy/8787

I though maybe something like this could work:

```
show(modify_doc, notebook_url='pangeo.esipfed.org/user/rsignell-usgs/proxy')
```

but that generated this URL:

```
http://pangeo.esipfed.org/user/rsignell-usgs/proxy:34560/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=870004ec-7366-4b38-b20f-2119e2b52327&bokeh-app-path=/user/rsignell-usgs/proxy:34560&bokeh-absolute-url=http://pangeo.esipfed.org/user/rsignell-usgs/proxy:34560&resources=none
```

that gave a `404` error.

I see there was a [Bokeh enhancement](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/7686) a few months ago that should allow this sort of interaction to work, and I gather I should be able to specify `notebook_url` to be a function to make this work, but I can't figure it out.

Is it clear what I'm doing wrong, or does someone have an example of how this works?

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh's documentation mentions some setup that you'll need to do to interface with a bokeh server when proxying through jupyterhub:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/notebook.html#jupyterhub

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: can you provide more detail on this? I am using Jupyterhub with Kubespawner. How can I pass the `EXTERNAL_URL` env variable as they mentioned in their example?